# how remove geoQuery.removeAllListeners inside method

Tags: java, android, geofire

I am building an app where I load `geoQuery = geofire.queryAtLocation` from mysql. I put the geoQuery into of `StringRequest` for load all positions, but when i try of remove the listeners, not work.

I test `geoQuery = geofire.queryAtLocation` into onCreate with a specific location, and work, the button for remove listener it remove.

The problem is when i put `geoQuery` inside another method and it wait load for execute.

How I do, for remove from button it looking `geoQuery` inside of a method and remove.?

My method for to load all position and it put in `geoQuery`

```
public void setGeoQuery(View view){
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("Response: ", response);

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String getObject = jObj.getString("saagMRK");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    latLng2 = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));

                        geoQuery = geofire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latLng2.latitude, latLng2.longitude), 0.1f);
                        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener()...
);//here
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
    }
```

This is my method for remove when I press button

```
public void ssGeo(View view) {
        geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
    }
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: hi, the error is when i press a button for remove geoQuery, don't work, is like if not finding geoQuery inside of Stringrequest, but when I put the only geoQuery in onCreate without Stringrequest, work!, but i need to get the locations from JSON